# Converting getOrElse into a object

Tags: scala, option-type

I have a part of my program that looks like this

```
  Option(request.getOverrides)
    .map(_ => convertOverrides(_))
    .getOrElse(FinalOverrideObject(""))
```

And its suppose to return a FinalOverrideObject and pass it into a a class that requires that object. But the getOrElse converts the output into any and I can not figure out how to convert it into a FinalOverrideObject at the end. Regardless of if the option is Some or None theres always a FinalOverrideObject being returned so it should be safe to cast, I just cant figure out how.

Comment: `map(_ => convertOverrides(_))` expands into `map(_ => x => convertOverrides(x))` so you are ignoring the value inside the **Some** and returning a **Function**, that is probably what is making the compiler infer **Any**, you can `map(x =>  convertOverrides(x))` or maybe just `map(convertOverrides)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option(request.getOverrides)
 .map(convertOverrides(_))
 .getOrElse(FinalOverrideObject(""))
```

Or otherwise:

```
Option(request.getOverrides)
 .map(o => convertOverrides(o))
 .getOrElse(FinalOverrideObject(""))
```

Or using fold:

```
    Option(request.getOverrides)
    .fold(FinalOverrideObject(""))(convertOverrides(_))
```